# Creating Excel from Database

Tags: c#, database, excel

I want to make Excel report when i click certain button. The data in Excel shows Transaction Number(Received ID) and the items(Material Name). One transaction number could contain one or more items. I have already code to make Excel report. But it's always error. Here is the code :

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Title = "Save Report";
sfd.FileName = ("Transaction History Report From").Replace("/","-"); // ganti slah jadi strip
sfd.Filter = "Excel FIle| *.xlsx";

/*
 * open dialog
 * -misValue pakai System.Reflection.Missing
 * -Excel.Range
 * -Excel : app,workbook,worksheet
 * -tarik data
 * -isi ke excel
 * 
 */
int row;
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //show dialog berhasil
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Excel.Range rng;

    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(misValue); // bikin workbook
    Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1); // nikin worksheet

    rng = ws.get_Range("A1:I1");
    rng.Merge();
    rng.Value = "Transaction History Report From" ;
    rng.Font.Bold = true;
    rng.Font.Size = 21;
    rng.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

    row = 3;
    ws.Cells[row, 1] = "TransactionID";
    ws.Cells[row, 2] = "Material";

    DataTable dttrID = con.executeSelect("SELECT receivedID FROM TrInventoryReceived WHERE receivedDate BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "'");
    row++;
    for (int i = 0; i < dttrID.Rows.Count; i++) //looping sebanyak transaksi yang ada
    {
        String transactionID = dttrID.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        DataTable material = con.executeSelect("SELECT materialID FROM TrStock WHERE receivedID ='" + transactionID + "'");

        ws.Cells[row + 4, 1] = transactionID;
        row++;
        for (int j = 0; j < material.Rows.Count; j++) //mengulang sebanyak data yang ada di detail transaction
        {
            DataTable Materianame = con.executeSelect("SELECT materialName FROM MsMaterial WHERE materialID ='" + material.Rows[j][0].ToString() + "'");

                ws.Cells[row + 4 + j, 2] = Materianame.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        }
    }

    ws.Columns.AutoFit();//buat nyamain uk7ran cellnyq sama kontenya

    wb.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    wb.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    app.Quit();

    releaseObject(ws);
    releaseObject(wb);
    releaseObject(app);    
    MessageBox.Show("Flie created");
}
```

The error message says "There is no row at position 0"

Also, i have `Class` `Connection` to connect to my database. Here is the code:

```
class Connect
{
    SqlConnection con;
    public Connect()
    {
        String connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public DataTable executeSelect(String query)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        return dt;
    }

    public void execute(String query)
    {

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

[My FOrm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R7ik.jpg)
Top `DatagGridVIew` is `TrInventoryReceived`, bottom is `TrStock` `Table`

Result sample in Excel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViSwi.jpg)

Can anyone help where the error is located in my code and how do i fix this?

Comment: that's `IndexOutOfRangeException` [An IndexOutOfRangeException exception is thrown when an invalid index is used to access a member of an array or a collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Read This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: How do i fix my code?

Comment: Yeah, That's possible to fix. You must debug by step in your `for` loop before that exception will be thrown , you will see over range index of array.

Comment: You can connect to an excel workbook using Oledb.  Then use BulkCopy to copy from a SQL Server database to an Oledb database.

Comment: How is the code? I don't fully understand in C#. I'm a newbie. Thank you before

Comment: Without reading through all of the code, are you trying to take the results of a query and put them in Excel?  If so, there is a fabulous tool called MsQuery, built into Excel.  You can do this in a codeless fashion, assuming you can get it into a single queries.  I see you have multiple queries, but without digging into them it's hard to see how the data in the tables relates to the output.

Comment: Can you show some sample data in the tables and what you want your output to look like?

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you. It's a method which exports a table from a database and saves it as an excel-file.
It uses a SqlConnection to connect to the database. When it reads the data it writes them to the excel-file at the same time.

This method exports the data to the excel-file:

```
public static void DataBaseToExcel(string connectionString, string table, string saveAs)
    {
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        app.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Item[1];
        List<string> ColumnsNames = GetColumnsNames(connectionString, table);
        int Row = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i != ColumnsNames.Count; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = ColumnsNames[i];
        }
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string commandString = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = commandString;
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int Column = 0; Column != ColumnsNames.Count; Column++)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[Row, Column + 1] = reader.GetValue(Column);
                        }
                        Row++;
                    }
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        workbook.SaveAs(saveAs);
        app.Quit();
    }
```

It additionally contains the headers of the columns, which I retrieve with this method:

```
public static List<string> GetColumnsNames(string connectionString, string table)
    {
        List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "select c.name from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id and t.name = '" + table + "' and t.type = 'U'";
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        columnNames.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return columnNames;
    }
```

Maybe you have to modify these methods for your purpose.